# Xcode/iOS Device Debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

When debugging an iOS app, i.e. iOS 8.1/8.2, when the app crashes somewhere it seems to only crash at either the `int main` in the `main.m` or it crashes in the actual assy code side of things.

Even with trying to step backwards, it never seems to let me step back at all.

I've tried recreating the schemes. I've checked that symbols aren't being stripped and that no optimisations are being done by the compiler in build settings.

Specifically this seems to only apply to debugging on the device rather than the simulator (which I never use anyway).

How do I get it to crash out at the Obj-C or Swift line which caused the exception/whatever.

Thanks

Ade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an **Exception Breakpoint** this will stop your code in the place an "Error" occured.

- Go to **Breakpoint Navigator** (<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>)
- Click on "+" sign on the bottom
- Choose **Add Exception Breakpoint**

[image]

**Exception Breakpoint** is not set on any line. Here are default settings:

[image]

Comment: Thats the issue I'm having... Despite looking at the call stack, sometimes, it's not so helpful so knowing where to place the exception breakpoint is a bit of a nightmare..

Can I put them at the beginning of methods so that at least the instigating method is flagged? Or does it have to be specifically that line?

The reason I ask is because one of my apps where exceptions happen has quite lengthy code due to it being shared between mac & iOS.

Comment: Exception Breakpoint is not set on any specific line. It should be called when exception occurs. Your app will stop exactly on the code which caused the exception.
See new screenshot.

Comment: many thanks! Wow... I never really toyed with the breakpoints, buts thats sure lead me to another load of WWDC + docs thats I can look through... Many thanks! Horrible thrown taken out of my proverbial paw!...

Comment: Out of interest, what did you use to make the screenshots? At the moment all I use are the OS X regulars i.e. cmd+ctrl+shift for a clipped shot. I was especially interested in how the latter of your images were zoomed as I often take shots for reference on my desktop :)

Comment: For the zoomed view: I have retina Macbook - that's why my screenshots are 2x bigger.

Comment: I'm not on retina so I'm relying on my iPhone 6+ and Macbook Air ro deal with that.. Hence the explanation as to why I don't use simulator... (just to add) when I get it right with those devices, I'll move on to others with friends and family as only so much is available as for now

Comment: Double yes!! if I could I'd up this again, but I'd just got an exception on an API fail that showed me which symbol it died on... Thanks for the quick answer again @Mateusz Szlosek... That's changed ALOT in my debugging life!!! BRAVO! Thanks Mateusz Szlosek

Answer (score 0):

xCode will usually show you main.c when crash occurs, this means only that the subroutine of something called within main.c was crashed.

The easiest way to find out what exactly crashed is to put breakpoint somewhere in your program, just before the point which could be suspicious from your opinion. If application crashes before breakpoint hits, put breakpoint earlier, until it hits before crash. When breakpoint is triggered, trace the application step by step to find out the exact reason for a crash.

Also, it often helpful to look into the call stack.

Comment: Deleted my last comment, but have a look at the accepted answer. That SURE helped me a lot out of selective debugging; i.e. selectively placing breakpoints and carrying on step by step to find the Exception area... Thanks for the help though..

I think what you're referring to is Cpp or C, which delves into the actual code rather than the Assy....